# The plug-in is broken, no module named resources

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am building the plug-in for QGIS by following this [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html).

When I am loading the plug-in, I am receiving the error The plug-in is broken, no module named resources.

Couldn't load plugin **SavingAttributes** due to an

> error when calling its classFactory() method.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you modify the interface with the QtDesigner and have resources in it and
when you save the file at least one line is added. 
You must delete it, the resources are already addressed in other modules of the plugin.

At the end of the *.ui file you have:

```
 <resources>
  <include location="resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
 </ui>
```

and you need:

```
 <resources>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I have not edit anything in the Qt yet. Just create a plugin with plugin builder and running the following command:
 
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc

Comment: This is a very common error. Which version of qgis do you use and which version is the plugin builder? I have `resources.py` instead of `resources_rc.py`. Say your plugin is called MyPlugin, please check MyPlugin.py for this line: `import resources`. Try to change it to `import resources_rc` or recompile resources to match that name.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! It has solved and working after replacing.

Comment: Can you help me in a more way? I am designing a plugin for filtering attributes. I am unable to perform it.

Comment: Simply ask a new question, so others can find it and contribute.